# How to override android tests path with Gradle?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, gradle, android-instrumentation

For historical reason instrumentation tests are not stored in `androidTests` directory [as required](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html) and i can't change directories structure (actually whole app is tests for the library used). I was able to build and install apk with gradle, but no tests were found:

```
:app-tests:connectedDebugAndroidTest
Tests on test_avd(AVD) - 4.1.2 failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException'

com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > No tests found.[test_avd(AVD) - 4.1.2] FAILED 
No tests found. This usually means that your test classes are not in the form that your test runner expects (e.g. don't inherit from TestCase or lack @Test annotations).
:app-tests:connectedDebugAndroidTest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app-tests:connectedDebugAndroidTest'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/project/app-tests/build/reports/androidTests/connected/index.html
```

Actually the tests are in `src` folder, written correctly and can be built/runned using Ant:

```
public abstract class BaseTest extends AndroidTestCase
{
...

public class AppInfoTest extends BaseTest
{
    @Test
    public void testAllProperties()
    {
        ...

...
```

How can i make Gradle process `src` folder as android (instrumentation) tests?

Here is my current `build.gradle` file (it uses the [experimental Android Gradle plugin](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental) version 0.7.2 because we have an NDK library):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 16
        buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "app.tests"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel 9
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 16
            versionCode 359
            versionName "1.3"

            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }

        sources {
            main {
                // overriding paths from default ones to actual ones
                // what about 'androidTests' ?
                manifest { source {
                    srcDir '.'
                    include 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                } }
                java { source { srcDirs = ['src'] } }
                res { source { srcDirs = ['res'] } }
                jni {
                    dependencies {
                        project ":library" // native library dependency
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':library')
}
```

**UPDATE 1 (for sschuberth)**:

Config:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 16
        buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "app.tests"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel 9
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 16
            versionCode 359
            versionName "1.3"

            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }

        sourceSets {
            androidTest {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml' // error here
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':library')
}
```

Error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/project/app-tests/build.gradle' line: 32

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app-tests'.
> Exception thrown while executing model rule: android { ... } @ app-tests/build.gradle line 16, column 5
   > Could not find property 'manifest' on source set 'android test'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was tricky solution: to use experimental gradle plugin to compile native code with NDK and regular gradle plugin for test app.

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    // experimental gradle plugin for the library to compile native code with NDK
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.2"

    // regular gradle plugin for the tests
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
  }
}

subprojects {
  task listAllDependencies(type: DependencyReportTask) {}
}
```

library gradle (experimental):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.library'

...

model {

    android {
      ...
      ndk {
          moduleName = "library-jni"
          cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
          cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
          stl = "c++_static"

          abiFilters.addAll(['armeabi-v7a', 'x86']) // supported abis only
       }
       ...
    }
    ...
}
```

app/build.gradle (regular):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

allprojects {
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
  }
}

repositories {
  mavenLocal()
  mavenCentral()
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 16
  buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "app.tests"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 16
    versionCode 359
    versionName "1.3"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }

  sourceSets {
    main {
      manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    }

    androidTest {
      manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
      java.srcDirs = ['src']

      jni {
        dependencies {
          project ":library"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  androidTestCompile project(':library')
  androidTestCompile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure this will work for your scenario, but you can update the root of the `androidTest` sourceSet like this

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        androidTest.setRoot('src')
    }
}
```

There is also a `test` source set if it's just Java code, nothing Android specific.

You could also play around with the `java.srcDir` setting...

The above setting will look at these locations for your files.

```
<project>/<module>/src/AndroidManifest.xml
<project>/<module>/src/java
```

If you'd like to move both into the `/src` directory, you can use

```
sourceSets {
    androidTest {
        setRoot 'src'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
    }
}
```

More Android Gradle details can be read at [Configuring the Structure](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Configuring-the-Structure)

---

You are welcome to debug these settings yourself with this setup

```
sourceSets {
    androidTest {
        setRoot 'src'
        java.srcDirs = ['./src']
    }

    println "androidTest.manifest.srcFile = ${androidTest.manifest.srcFile}"
    println "androidTest.java.srcDirs = ${androidTest.java.srcDirs}"
}
```

When you just clean the project, you'll see those lines being printed to the console

Comment: `> Could not find method manifest() for arguments [build_5blgy0rxz915fycj6huh3b3bg$_run_closure3$_closure6$_closure8$_closure9$_closure10@46935c97] on source set 'main'.` probably it's because experimental gradle plugin. Also i've checked to add it not in 'main' source set but in SourceSets just like in example on the link

Comment: Not sure why you are telling me an error for something that existed in your original code. I don't show a manifest closure

Comment: Yeah, and like I said, I don't know about your error because it's referring to the `manifest` setting, which I didn't say anything about. You're welcome to check the link in my answer to see how to correctly identify the manifest file for a source set

Comment: i've followed the link but it's not working as in example

Comment: yes, it requires a manifest since the test app is actually regular app with instrumented code. what error do you mean?

Comment: The error in your updated question. The test directory is simply for test code like Mockito, JUnit, etc. The "instrumented code" that you are testing goes in the `main` sourceSet, which is where the Manifest is.

Comment: there is no `test` directory set anywhere in the updated question: `src` is used for android tests: `androidTest { java.srcDirs = ['src'] }`

Comment: What exactly is preventing you from moving the test code into recommended `androidTests` folder?

Comment: it's configured to be built with Ant and Maven and i can't break something while adding something. so the directory structure will be the same

Comment: Okay, then you could write a Gradle task to execute the Ant/Maven tasks instead of messing around with Gradle location settings

Comment: it was expected to be easy (set non-standard paths) , but it's not in fact. do you know how to do it?

Comment: Personally, I haven't ever needed to modify Gradle sourceSet paths from the defaults. The link that I provided in my answer describes the settings that you would use if you were migrating from an Eclipse project, where you would have everything in the `src/` directory like you are describing. I've updated my answer with some additional details

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `sources {}` you should use `sourceSets {}` and the `androidTest` source set to customize the test source code location:

```
model { // Required for experimental plugin.
    android {
        sourceSets {
            androidTest {
                manifest.srcFile '../AppTest/AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['../AppTest/src']
                res.srcDirs = ['../AppTest/res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['../AppTest/assets']
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this not *not* apply to unit test. For unit test (like with [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/)), use the `test` source set.

Comment: not working: `* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app-tests'.
> Exception thrown while executing model rule: android { ... } @ app-tests/build.gradle line 16, column 5
   > Could not find method manifest() for arguments [build_5blgy0rxz915fycj6huh3b3bg$_run_closure3$_closure6$_closure8$_closure9$_closure10@a3d6b33] on source set 'android test'.` Also pay attention that experimental plugin syntax is different from mainstream one.

Comment: This is not experimental plugin syntax, I've been using it since 2015. Also the source set should be called `androidTest` not `android test`.

Comment: i'm using experimental gradle plugin (0.7.2) and the code above is NOT working for it

Comment: I was missing the outer `model` closure. I've edited my answer.